# jQuery Displaying Different Elements (divs) when hovering over other specific elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

**FIDDLE >>** http://jsfiddle.net/8bwSD/1/

I'm making a website using HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery.

I have a gallery of images. All images have an info box (simple div with some styling) situated within them.

When hovering over the info box, relevant information is shown.

Below is the jQuery to show/hide (slide in/out) the relevant info:

```
$(".info").hover(function(){
  $(".cap2").slideDown(400);
}, function(){
   $(".cap2").slideUp(300);
});
```

The info for the images sits inside the HTML.

The 'info' boxes (which are to be hovered over) are also inside the HTML.

Currently, image info and info boxes have their own CSS styling, **so whenever I hover over one info box, information is displayed for ALL images at the same time.**

So my **QUESTION** is:

Is there a way to create clean/simple code to show relevant information for each image without having to create seperate CSS styling and jQuery code for each and every info box?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you need to share the html sample for us to see the relationship between `info` and `cap2` elements

Comment: if cap2 is a descendant of info then try `$(this).find(".cap2").slideDown(400);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the fiddle now - if you could help it would be great!

To clear things up: In short: I want each 'i' to display its own unique information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".info").hover(function () {
    $(this).closest(".imgcontainer").find(".cap2").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).closest(".imgcontainer").find(".cap2").hide();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bwSD/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 .hover(function () {
        $(this).next(".cap2")
            .show();
    }, function () {
        $(".cap2")
            .hide();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bwSD/2/

**Update**

As Milimetric points out you can use `next` on the hover out function as well.  This should improve performance because jQuery does not need to look for all `.cap2` elements in the dom just the `next` one to hide it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".info").hover(function () {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).next(".cap2").show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).next(".cap2").hide();
    });
});
```

Milimetric's fiddle for reference

jsfiddle.net/8bwSD/4

Comment: I like that but use .next('.cap2') for both functions, it's probably a little more performant.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/8bwSD/4/

Comment: Thank you Trevor, but for some reason I couldn't get it to work on mine. Hiral's seems to do the trick though - I must be doing something wrong, but thank you for your time!

Comment: @Alex its not working for you in the fiddle?  If its not working in your code then your html structure must be different then the fiddle you provided..